# Resizing constraints jQuery .resizable()

Tags: jquery, html, css

I try to force jquery resizing in width, i explain:

I have a resizable element in a container:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="resizableObj"></div>
</div>
```

My container had a fixed width:

```
.container{
    width:160px;
    background-color:red;
}
```

I want to resize height and at the same time,i want that the container height grow. 
The only thing that i need is to constraint the width resizing.

I can't do it with the maxWidth property because i have more than one resizing object and they are placed at different position in the container.

If i use the "containment:'.container'" option, i can't enlarge my container if i resiz my object at the bottom of it, but i'm constrained width.

So what i can do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/119/

Js:

```
$('.resizableObj').each(function () {
var d = $(this);
var maxW = parseInt(d.attr('data-maxwidth'));
d.resizable({
    maxWidth: maxW,        
    resize:function(event,ui){
        var H=0;
        $('.resizableObj').each(function(){
            var div = $(this);
            H+=div.outerHeight(true);                
        });
        $('.container').height(H+20);
        if(d[0].getBoundingClientRect().right>$('.container')[0].getBoundingClientRect().right){
            console.log('outside');
            $(this).resizable('widget').trigger('mouseup');
        }            
    }
});
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
 <div data-maxwidth="120" class="resizableObj"></div>
 <div data-maxwidth="220" class="resizableObj"></div>
 <div data-maxwidth="340" class="resizableObj"></div>
 <div data-maxwidth="30" class="resizableObj"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank for your answer, i faced an issue with your code, even on your fiddle. The width resizing work great on x axis, exactly what i want. But on Y, i resize, it stop, and i need to release the mouse to continue.

Comment: it's ok for the height, i can resize the object how i want and i don't need to release the mouse. 

The problem is now on the width. http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2014/20/1400146293-resize.jpg The max resize value on X axis need to be forced to the container. I don't need to be able to go out, whatever the .resizable() element position on the container.

Comment: i faced a new problem with your code, when i touch the right border of the container, the object is stick to it and it's hard to reduce it. 

Anyway, i think that it will be ok, i will try to use the properties that you gave me: getBoundingClientRect().right, think i can succes with this !

http://jsfiddle.net/5nz2V/ Only with something like this.

Thank for your help !

Comment: Well, that's not the issue exactly. Whenever the div moves out of the container, "mouseup" is triggered which releases the resize handles. In order to resize again, you need to select the div again for that matter. As far as getBoundingClientRect is concerned it contains top,left,right,bottom,height,width value of the element. You can find more on internet

Comment: Yeah, the problem is with the mouseup, because the mouseup is not exactly on the d[0].getBoundingClientRect().right.right but a little after, so we need to click, move one pixel, click again, move one pixel, until d[0].getBoundingClientRect().right<d[0].getBoundingClientRect().right

Comment: Yeah exactly. And that's the only way to cancel the resizing from resize function

Comment: The other solution was to add containment:parent in resizable options, instead of that if loop. but the problem is that by adding this, Y axis resizing is not smooth.